# I want to stop the browser request, when user clicks on any button from UI, like stop button on browser

Tags: javascript

I want to stop the browser request, when user clicks on any button from UI, like stop button on browser. I want to do it through javascript.

Comment: In firefox, even you manually press the stop button it does not completely stop. It only stops loading the main document, but it continues to load other elements such as images. I hate firefox.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try a few things .. I looked at a [forum here](http://forums.devshed.com/html-programming-1/does-window-stop-work-in-ie-1311.html)

followings from that ..

In Netscape, `window.stop()` seems to work (in the same way as the Stop button on the browser I guess). However, this does not work in IE.

> I don't think you can stop the processing in IE, but you might try one
>   of the following:
>
> Event.cancelBubble this is IE only and stops EVENT propogation.
>   However, once the event has occurred (onSubmit, onClick or whatever
>   you used to start the download), I'm not sure this will stop it.
>
> Event.reason IE only. Reason holds the value of the code specifying
>   the status of the data transfer. 0=successful, 1=aborted, 2=error. I
>   don't remember if this is readonly. If it is not, perhaps you can
>   assign a value of 1 to abort the transfer.
>
> Event.returnValue IE only. I'll quote this one. 'If returnValue is
>   set, its value takes precedent over the value actually received by an
>   event handler. Set this property to false to cancel the default action
>   fo the sourece element on which the event occured.'
>
> Play with these a bit. I don't see anything else that might work. If
>   they don't do anything to stop the process, it probably can't be done.

I found a way to do this after a lot of research - use

document.execCommand("Stop");

This works in IE.

Answer (score 23):

As Amit Doshi and Slaks code suggests you can do that. But I find it more efficient to do a try and catch.

There is only one alternative to `window.stop()` so trying it first with a fallback (for Internet Explorer) is the way to go to support all browsers:

```
try {
    window.stop();
} catch (exception) {
    document.execCommand('Stop');
}
```

Comment: This is a complete solution; although window.stop is not part of any specification it does seem to be an accepted DOM API.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is more flexible

```
"stop" in window ? window.stop() : document.execCommand("Stop");
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use below code for cross browsers solution.
I tried it with FF3.5.2, Safari 3.1 and IE 7 and 8 its working fine

```
if(navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
    window.document.execCommand('Stop');
else
    window.stop();
```

Comment: Basing code on browser name is bad practices. You should use Jose's try/catch approach instead which is feature based and more resilient.