# How to fix this error dealing with an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to stop a file from uploading when the user clicks on the "Cancel" button. To do this I am thinking of stopping the transport inside the iframe. The problem is be able to code this correctly. Below is the code of what I am trying to achieve but I am getting this error when I click on the "Cancel" button:

```
Uncaught exception: [Exception.... “Not enough arguments [nslDOMHTML.Document.execCommand]” nresult: “0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)” location: “JS frame;; https://......../QandATable.php = <TOP_LEVEL> ;; line 765” data: no]
```

First of all how can this  error be fixed and second how can the code below be written correctly so that when the "Cancel" button is clicked on, it stops the transport inside the iframe?

Below is the startImageUpload() function where it starts uploading a file. Within that function is the function which handles the "Cancel" button when it is clicked;

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){


              $(".imageCancel").click(function() {
              $('.upload_target')[0].contentwindow

              if ($('.upload_target')[0].contentWindow.document.execCommand)
    { // IE browsers
       $('.upload_target')[0].contentWindow.document.execCommand('Stop');
    }
else
    { // other browsers
        $('.upload_target')[0].contentWindow.stop();
    }


          return stopImageUpload();

    });

      return true;
}
```

Below is the form code which consists of the iframe:

```
 var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return startImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
    "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
    "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" + 
    "</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'><label>" + 
    "<input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' /></label></p>" + 
    "<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the `Stop` command is not supported.

Comment: Oh, ok then, is there another method which could be used to stop the transport within a iframe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734429/how-can-i-cancel-stop-uploading-of-a-file-in-ie-javascript "it is not possible to cancel upload.". you could google "javascript stop upload" to try to find a partial solution/hack that may fit your requirement.

Comment: I just looked at the link you gave me, I was a little confused, so did PeterF managed to find a way of somehow not sending the file to server side or not? He marked the answer but he did state it is not possible cancelling the upload?