# Stop reloading the page after location.reload(); has been called

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link to reload the page with JS:

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.reload()">Reload</a>
```

How do I stop page reload after the location.reload() method has been called?

Comment: Somewhat confusing. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: can't you remove `location.reload()`?

Comment: @vijayP If you want to refresh the page in your browser, you can click the reload button. You can then stop the reload by clicking the stop reload button (the times icon). So the question was how do I stop page reloading with JS after the location.reload() method has been called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to stop the browser request, when user clicks on any button from UI, like stop button on browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286675/i-want-to-stop-the-browser-request-when-user-clicks-on-any-button-from-ui-like)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
window.stop();
```

**Beware**: Microsoft Internet Explorer and Edge don't support it.

Comment: Thanks Angel, I will try it now.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, or am I missing something? https://jsfiddle.net/446ccjLt/1/

Comment: It works for me, because I have a slow PC. Try using it on a website that has more content. Currently, on that empty fiddle, it's impossible  for the hand to click on time the `stop`.