# Automatic click Submit after 10 seconds in php using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to auto submit for after `10s` in `PHP` using `jquery`. but no action is done.

I tried:

```
<?php echo "<div class="page-header">
            <h1 class="h2"></h1>
        </div>
        <script>
            var checkState = function(){
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'check_diffex.php?od=$scdate'
      }).done(function(data){
        if(data.diffex >= 10) {
        $('#quizsb').submit();          
      });    
    }    
    checkState();    
            </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jque‌​ry.min.js"></script>
    <form method="post" action="qform.php?srn=<?php echo $srn ?>&id=<?php echo $id ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" id="quizsb">
.....
</form
"?>
```

**check_diffex.php**

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if(isset($_GET['od'])){
    $deotd = $_GET['od'];
}
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$cdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', time());
$scdate = strtotime($cdate);

$e = $scdate - $deotd;

// You would calculate a real value here
echo json_encode([
  'diffex' => $e
]);
?>
```

> Before Answering Please look at this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047992/automatic-click-submit-after-10-seconds-in-php-using-jquery#comment81043307_47047992)

Comment: You included more than 1 jQuery script (3 in total) in your code, and it's an old version. Why?

Comment: @Raptor Ooops that's my mistake, removed. But then also it didn't work... Which one is the latest version?

Comment: why dont you use setTimeout with 10 seconds?

Comment: @tan my function will be used for the quiz which is to be submitted after 10s (example) of playing, if I use `setTimeout` user can every time increase there time by refreshing...

Comment: If you don't mind security, you can use JS codes to `clearTimeout` and `setTimeout` in your "game" logic.

Comment: @Raptor What do you mean by no security? I am not getting it.

Comment: As JS is a client-side scripting, its output can easily be changed in Developer Console, i.e. people can cheat at this way.

Answer (score 1):

use setTimeout function.
Below code submit form automatically after 10sec from page load

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Submit form" button to submit the form.</p>

<form id="myForm" action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
</form>

<script>
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("myForm").submit(); }, 10000);
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047992/automatic-click-submit-after-10-seconds-in-php-using-jquery#comment81043307_47047992

Comment: why don't you use [browser stop](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_stop.asp) function

Comment: use document.execCommand("Stop"); details are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286675/i-want-to-stop-the-browser-request-when-user-clicks-on-any-button-from-ui-like)

Answer (score 0):

Use Cookie instead if you don't want user to increase timeout, so set Cookie with 10 seconds lifetime and delete the cookie after that. Please apply your logic to delete the cookie after 10 seconds and always check if the cookie is set or not, if it is not, then submit the form.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Please look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47047992/automatic-click-submit-after-10-seconds-in-php-using-jquery#comment81043307_47047992